# Setting File From Internal To Public

Tags: c#, settings

When I create project with settings file. The access modifier is internal. How to change it to public ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either select "public" in the combobox "Access modifier" in settings designer:

[image]

Or you can manually set that settings class to be public in generated code:

[image]